# What is the story behind ${n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

By exploring the inductive proof from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519832/proving-by-induction-that-sum-k-0nn-choose-k-2n)

I came to the point where I did not understand this step:

$${n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}$$

There is a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Inductive_proof) article but it does not make much sense to me.

**What is the idea behind this "trick"?**

Comment: All $k$-subsets of an $n+1$ element set $\{1,2,...,n+1\}$  can be split into two parts: those who contain $n+1$ and those who don't. How many are of the first and of the second kind?...

Comment: @PeterFranek But isn't $n+1$ missing for ${n \choose k}$?

Comment: Exactly the same as the above comment but in a different format: Expand $(x+1)^{n+1}$ = $(x+1)(x+1)^{n}$ and look at the $x^k$ term.

Comment: @Asvin I do not quite get the analogy at least not at this point. Would prefer to stay with the probability example

Comment: When you expand $(x+1)^n$, $x^k$ requires you to pick k brackets out of the n ones we have and choose a $x$ from them and $1$ from others. It is an important idea but if you don't understand it now, just remember it and come back to it later. I don't understand what you mean by a $n+1$ missing in peter's comment.

Comment: Let's take a set $S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}$. Let's say that it has $n = 5$ elements and the $n+1$ element would be $6$. Now we want to now the number of possible combinations when we choose three elements from the set. With $n+1$ this number would be ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ this should now be equal to ${5 \choose 3} + {5 \choose 2} = 20$ (which is by the way true). However now $n = 5$ so our $6$ is not anymore in the set we use for combination $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ this confuses  me.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-pascals-rule-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose (and other questions linked there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identity just splits the ${n+1 \choose k}$ subsets into two types: those subsets that contain a given element, and those subsets that do not contain this given element.

Let's call the set of $n+1$ elements $S$ and pick one element $x \in S$.

So first, how many subsets of $S$ of size $k$ contain $x$? Well apart from $x$ there are $n$ elements in $S$. Formally, $|S-\{x\}| = n$. We want subsets of size $k$ and we already have $x$ in our subset. Thus we need to pick $k-1$ elements from $S-\{x\}$. Thus the total number of these subsets is ${n \choose {k-1}}$.

Second, how many subsets of $S$ of size $k$ do not contain $x$?
Now we need to pick $k$ elements from $S-\{x\}$, which gives ${n \choose k}$ subsets.

All subsets of $S$ of size $k$ either contain $x$ or not, so we have counted all of them, and found that
$${n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}.$$

Comment: If $S1 = \{1,2 ,3, \dots, n, n+1\}$ and $S2 = S1 - (n+1) = \{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$. When $(n+1) \in K$ shouldn't than $\vert K \vert > \vert S2 \vert$?

Answer (score 5):

Although the combinatorial proof is definitely the "correct" one, you can also prove Pascal's identity using brute force, by expanding the binomial coefficients:
$$
\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!} = \frac{n!((n-k+1)+k)}{k!(n-k+1)!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k+1)!} = \binom{n+1}{k}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

One is choosing $k$ balls out of $n+1$ is same as choosing with those $n+1$ set broken and the other one is due to property of pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 
$$ {n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
Next,
$$ {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-(k-1))!}$$ 
which is equal to 
$$\frac{n\cdot(n-1)...2\cdot1}{(k\cdot(k-1)...2\cdot1)((n-k)\cdot(n-k-1)...2\cdot1)}+\frac{n\cdot(n-1)...2\cdot1}{((k-1)\cdot(k-2)...2\cdot1)((n-k+1)\cdot(n-k)...2\cdot1)}$$
which is equal to
$$\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\Big(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k+1}\Big) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\Big(\frac{(n-k+1)+k}{k(n-k)}\Big)=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\Big(\frac{n+1}{k(n-k+1)}\Big)=\frac{(n+1)\cdot n\cdot(n-1)...2\cdot1}{(k\cdot(k-1)...2\cdot1)((n-k+1)\cdot(n-k)...2\cdot1)}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot n\cdot(n-1)...2\cdot1}{(k\cdot(k-1)...2\cdot1)(((n+1)-k)\cdot(n-k)...2\cdot1)}=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1)-k)!}={(n+1) \choose k}$$

Yuval Filmus' answer came while I was typing out my answer. Just expanded on his solution I guess?