# Prove $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{m+i}{i}=\binom{m+n+1}{n}$ (another Hockey-Stick Identity?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer, and $m$ a positive integer. Could someone explain to me why the identity
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{m+i}{i}=\binom{m+n+1}{n}
$$
holds?

Comment: You may want to see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784613/another-hockey-stick-identity. (Replace their $r$ with your $n$ and their $n$ with your $m+1$.)

Comment: This is easy to show by induction ... try it ?

Comment: Alternative answer ... Yes someone can explain it !

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I know that it's done by induction but still sure how. So yes, I've tried it.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth It's almost impossible to keep the terms straight but I substituted my stuff over to the best reply on that post but it still isn't very clear. Do you know the induction method?

Comment: Try inducting on $n$. The main part is (the inductive step) assuming that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\binom{m+i}{m} = \binom{m+n+1}{m+1}$ and showing that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+1}\binom{m+i}{m} = \binom{m+n+2}{m+1}$ (I used $\binom{a}{b} = \binom{a}{a-b}$ in some places so the lower number in the binomial coefficients may not look the same as in your original post). You may also want to recall [Pascal's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190617/what-is-the-story-behind-n1-choose-k-n-choose-k-n-choose-k-1/1190639) to help you.

Comment: If you think of it in terms of "Pascal"'s triangle, it's obvious. It's the sum of a 'diagonal' starting with 1. Use the fact that the sum of two adjacent terms gives the term on the next row.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{m + i \choose i}} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{i}{-m -i + i - 1 \choose i}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{i}{-m - 1 \choose i} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{i}\bracks{z^{i}}\pars{1 + z}^{-m - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}\pars{1 + z}^{-m - 1}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{i}
=
\bracks{z^{0}}\pars{1 + z}^{-m - 1}\,
{\pars{-1/z}^{n + 1} - 1 \over \pars{-1/z} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}\pars{1 + z}^{-m - 1}\,
{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} - z^{n + 1} \over -1 - z}
\,{z \over z^{n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{-m - 2}\,
\bracks{z^{n + 1} - \pars{-1}^{n + 1}} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{-m - 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{n}{-m - 2 \choose n} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\bracks{{m + 2 + n - 1\choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{m + n + 1 \choose n} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: The color `#ffd` is so ease to work with :)

Comment: @LeAnhDung It clearly shows the very beginning while the box shows the very end.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\sum_{q=0}^n {m+q\choose q} = \sum_{q\ge 0} {m+q\choose q} [[0\le q\le n]]
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} {m+q\choose q} [z^n] \frac{z^q}{1-z}
= [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z}  \sum_{q\ge 0} {m+q\choose q} z^q
\\= [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}}
= [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+2}}
= {n+m+1\choose n}.$$