# Hard? Inequality with binomial coefficients and powers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Could you help me?

I’m working in *Sohrab Real Analysis* and I have the following exercise:

Proof that for all ${n}\in\mathbb{N}$  we have

$\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2}\dots\binom{n}{n-1}\le(\frac{2^n-2}{n-1})^{n-1}$

I tried by induction over n and obtain the follow:
If we suppose true for ${k}\in\mathbb{N}$ , then the in the inductive step I obtained

$\binom{k+1}{1}\binom{k+1}{2}\dots\binom{k+1}{k}\le{(k+1)}(\frac{2^{k+1}-2}{2(k-1)}-\frac{1}{k-1})^{k-1}$

And I don’t know how to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the [AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/691807/215011):
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k}k\ge\sqrt[k]{a_1a_2\cdots a_k}$$
Think about what value for $k$ you should use and what $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_k$ (all of them positive) must be.

([Second hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519832/215011))